# How to remove elements from a Javascript array?

Tags: javascript

I want to remove some element in my array using splice method with if condition in my iteration. I do the following:

```
var list = [{type:"product",name:"Product A"},{type:"product",name:"Product B"},{type:"service", name:"Service A"},{type:"service", name:"Service B"}]

list.forEach(function (item, index) {
    if (item.type == 'service'){
        list.splice(index, 1)
    }
}

//result: list = list = [{type:"product",name:"Product A"},{type:"product",name:"Product B"},{type:"service", name:"Service A"}]

//expected: list = [{type:"product",name:"Product A"},{type:"product",name:"Product B"}]
```

I expect the both element with type "service" will be removed, but only the first element is removed.

Comment: Your approach didn't work because when you reached second service, the index: 3 doesn't exist in your array anymore because after your first splice your array length became 3 so last index is 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `forEach()`, [***If the array is modified during iteration, other elements might be skipped***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#If_the_array_is_modified_during_iteration_other_elements_might_be_skipped.)

Why don't use [**`Array.prototype.filter()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

> The `filter()` method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

```js
var list = [{type:"product",name:"Product A"},{type:"product",name:"Product B"},{type:"service", name:"Service A"},{type:"service", name:"Service B"}]

list = list.filter( item => item.type != 'service');
console.log(list);
```

Comment: Should you not vote it as dupe instead?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Code:

```js
const list = [{type:"product",name:"Product A"},{type:"product",name:"Product B"},{type:"service", name:"Service A"},{type:"service", name:"Service B"}];

const resultList = list.filter(item => item.type !== 'service');

console.log(resultList);
```

Comment: Should you not vote it as dupe instead?

Comment: Thanks for quick response. Problem solved.